# Why was this question closed on grounds of being unclear?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

I don't understand why [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/276690/) was closed? Especially why on grounds of being *unclear*? It was quite clear, was it not?

Comment: Well, several hints/questions in the comments went unremarked-upon by the OP and the question was not edited to clarify. At some level it was unclear what the OP was unclear about.